# How to debug "suspend-then-hibernate" returning "Failed to read time: -9"?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I have been using `suspend-then-hibernate` on my laptop to suspend and have it go to hibernation after a delay. This used to work just fine.

Recently, this command is not working anymore. When I run it, the screen goes black, and then the login screen shows up as it just locked my account.

I ran `sudo systemctl status systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service` and it shows the following:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Suspend; Idle into hibernate...
systemd-sleep[31822]: Failed to read time: -9
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend; Idle into hibernate.
```

If I ran the command without sudo, I get `Failed to put system into suspend followed by hibernate via logind: Access denied`.

Both suspend and hibernate work well.

Any idea on how to debug/fix this issue?